# how to hide the supporting files(txt,xml) used, while creating ios framework

Tags: ios, xcode

**What i do:**

1.I builded an IOS project in xcode,which contain some specific logics.

2.So i changed the product to **framework** and generated framework for the logics which has some supporting(xml,txt) files.

3.While using the framework in other projects,i need to use the xml and txt files in the project.

**What i need to do:**

1.I need to hide the xml and txt files used in the framework. ie)while importing the framework in other projects ,i dont want others to view/know the xml and txt file used in the project(It must be private).

**What i need to know:**

1.Is there any way to hide the supporting files(xml,txt) used inside the framework?

Comment: There is no way to do this other than using `.` filenames or chflags; even so they are not really hidden.

Comment: Is it a Cocoa Touch Framework?

Comment: There is no fundamental of extensions in UNIX, so you can name the file to anything which is not understandable, your framework will still be able to read those files without extension.

Comment: @KrishnaCA yes its a Cocoa Touch Framework.

Comment: @iphonic @ l'L'l Thanks for the reply

Comment: Doesn't these files get hidden by default in a Cocoa Touch Framework?